# Why library that is responsible for checking phone number is not working?

Tags: flask

I am trying to validate a phone number in the field using the following code from `twilio blog`:

**in app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import phonenumbers
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, ValidationError

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top-secret!'
Bootstrap(app)


class PhoneForm(FlaskForm):
    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate_phone(self, phone):
        try:
            p = phonenumbers.parse(phone.data)
            if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(p):
                raise ValueError()
        except (phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException, ValueError):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = PhoneForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['phone'] = form.phone.data
        return redirect(url_for('show_phone'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


@app.route('/showphone')
def show_phone():
    return render_template('show_phone.html', phone=session['phone'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**in templates/base.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    {% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/16.0.4/css/intlTelInput.css">
    {% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% block scripts %}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/16.0.4/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**in index.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Flask Phone Number Input Demo{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Flask Phone Number Input Demo</h1>

<form method="POST">
  {{form.hidden_tag()}}
  {{ form.phone }} <br>
  {{ form.submit }}
</form>


{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>
        var wtf_phone_field = document.getElementById('phone');
        wtf_phone_field.style.position = 'absolute';
        wtf_phone_field.style.top = '-9999px';
        wtf_phone_field.style.left = '-9999px';
        wtf_phone_field.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><input type="tel" id="_phone"></div>');
        var fancy_phone_field = document.getElementById('_phone');
        var fancy_phone_iti = window.intlTelInput(fancy_phone_field, {
            separateDialCode: true,
            utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/16.0.4/js/utils.js",
        });
        fancy_phone_iti.setNumber(wtf_phone_field.value);
        fancy_phone_field.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            wtf_phone_field.value = fancy_phone_iti.getNumber();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**in show_phone.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Phone Number Input for Flask{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Flask Phone Number Input Demo</h1>
<p>The number that you entered is <b>{{ session['phone'] }}</b>.</p>
<p><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Enter another!</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Code is **working** (it brings me to the `show_phone.html` page that shows me my number) if I comment on the function that supposes to verify the phone number, e.g. def `validate_phone(self, phone)`, however with this function when I click the submit button **nothing happens** - looks like the function stops it, but there is *no error* as well! What is the problem with this function, it seems correct for me?

Comment: What are your changes exactly that causes the function to stop working? I am not sure if I understood your description correctly.
Can you also provide a example number for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can only guess that function raises an exception (due to an incorrect number?) which causes the validation to fail.

As `form.validate_on_submit()` evaluates to `False` you will be forwarded to `index.html` which looks like nothing happened.

I would recommend to set some breakpoints and debug the function. This should help you to find the issue.